# Формула вычисления размера ползунка для скролла

Tags: математика, прокрутка

Помогите с формулой для вычисления размера ползунка для скролла блока, относительно высоты видимой области

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Высота ползунка должна относится к высоте рабочей области скроллбара (без кнопок по концам) так, как высота видимой области относится к высоте всей страницы.

```
ratio = Min(visibleHeight / totalHeight, 1.0); // процент видимой области
thumbHeight = scrollHeight * ratio;
```

Comment: что будет содержать переменная scrollHeight и как ее вычислить?